# Script to pick a variable file for use in the Excel Connection Manager

Tags: ssis

I need your help. I have an SSIS package which picks the file from a folder and loads it into a SQL table. The problem I have is that the file name has a date time stamp so every time a load commences, this file name will change.

Can you please suggest how to deal with this and if possible provide an example script for this because I don't have any experience with VB.NET

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Foreach Loop Container`. Change the Foreach Loop Containers collection to use the `Foreach File Enumerator`, this should be the default option. Point the folder of the enumerator to the folder that contains your files.

If new files get inserted to the folder then you should delete them or move files that are processed to a sub folder so they won't be processed twice. You can do this with the `File System Task`.

Comment: But Every time i'll have only one file in my folder and name A-24-6-13 for today and other day i'll replaced by A-25-6-13,

Comment: It is still the easiest solution to use a `Foreach Loop container`. Unless you wanna do something complicated to just retrieve the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If for example you are retrieving only the latest file from a specified directory. This can be done using a **Script Task** as your first element in your control flow, before your data flow task.

What you can do is:

- Create a variable for which you will pass a FilePath string to. This would initially contain the directory path and after the script task retrieves the correct file name for the latest file it would be updated to be used in your Excel Source.
- Your first element in your control flow will be your Script Task.
  This script task will contain the following code which looks for the latest file in the directory looking for a specific pattern. *You need to import the System.IO library*:

```cs
public void Main()
{
  // Specify a pattern to look for specific files.
  string pattern = "YOURFILE*.txt";
  string directoryPath = this.Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
  string file = GetFile(directoryPath, pattern);

  this.Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value = file;
}

private static string GetFile(string directory, string pattern)
{
  DirectoryInfo theDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
  FileInfo theLatestFile = GetLatestFile(theDirectory, pattern);
  return theLatestFile.ToString();
}

// Retrieve latest file in specific directory following a given pattern.
private static FileInfo GetLatestFile(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string pattern)
{
  if (directoryInfo == null || !directoryInfo.Exists)
    return null;

  FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern);
  DateTime lastWrite = DateTime.MinValue;
  FileInfo lastWritenFile = null;

  foreach (FileInfo file in files)
  {
    if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
    {
      lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
      lastWritenFile = file;
    }
  }
  return lastWritenFile;
}
```

- Having found the file and refreshed your File variable, you can use an expression to populate the **ExcelFilePath** property for your Excel source.

**N.B!** Make sure you select the **ExcelFilePath**, not the **ConnectionString** property.